# org.apache.kafka.common.errors.UnknownTopicOrPartitionException: This server does not host this topic-partition

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

Using `java` I am sending a `json object`  to kafka, initially it worked for me for 2 days, now I am getting the following `exception`

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.UnknownTopicOrPartitionException: This server does not host this topic-partition.
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.FutureRecordMetadata.valueOrError(FutureRecordMetadata.java:65)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.FutureRecordMetadata.get(FutureRecordMetadata.java:52)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.FutureRecordMetadata.get(FutureRecordMetadata.java:25)
    at dummy.DummySyntheticManifestProducer.main(DummySyntheticManifestProducer.java:164)
 Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.UnknownTopicOrPartitionException: This server does not host this topic-partition.
```

Comment: Thanks for posting this. Could also please provide some information as to how is your Kafka setup where you saw this issue? Are you using a cluster or is it a standalone server? What version of Kafka are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

setting the `retries` property on the producer settings.
also need to set the property `max.in.flight.requests.per.connection` to 1

Comment: Why did this fix your problem?

Comment: Guess it's buried in the chamber of the secrets ¯\_(ツ)_/¯